# Java SSH Ganymed - Random error to try to connect with username and password

Tags: java, ssh

We are using the library for connecting via ssh with an username and password. Sometimes, the method **connection.authenticateWithPassword** return false(received message: SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE), and others, works correctly returning true.
The username and password are correct in all cases.

At the moment to try to connect, many methods are availables: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic and password. Among them is present the password method, and in fact, the **connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(this.username, "password")** method  returns true.

We have added the library logging but we haven't found any error until now.

Any idea for help us?

```java
private Connection createConnection() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        logger.debug("Creating ssh connection...");

        Connection connection = new Connection(this.ip, this.port);
        connection.setTCPNoDelay(this.tcpNoDelay);
        connection.connect(null, this.connectTimeout, this.kexTimeout);     

        if(connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(this.username, "password")) {
            if(!connection.authenticateWithPassword(this.username, this.password)) {
                logger.debug("Authentication failed!");
                connection.close();
                throw new IOException("Authentification failed");
            }
        } else {
            logger.debug("Authentication password method is not available!!");
        }

        logger.debug("Connection was created successfull!");
        return connection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more detail on the success and failures. Its not clear whether the success and failures are random on a single device, or that you successfully authenticate to one device, but it fails against another?

If its failing consistently against a specific device then what authentication options are reported by the device?

Comment: We have two different devices but the behaviour is random for both. Sometimes one device responds successfull and then it responds fail.
The connection is opened, it is used and then it is closed. Always the connections are closed.

Should we have to wait more time between the invocation to connection.connect and connection.authenticateWithPassword methods?
Or do you think there is another problem?

Comment: You should probably up the logging level to see if there are any hint of the problem in the logs. If random attempts fail and you are sure the password is correct then you should examine the server for indications as to why.